# Audit user login/logout activity in Airflow

Tags: airflow, audit-logging, airflow-webserver

I am using Airflow version 2.5.0.

Is there a way for an admin to see logging information about users' login/logout activity, as well as failed login attempts?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [official docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#webserver), for example, you can set session_lifetime_minutes might be valuable to you.

Comment: I could not find something relevant in the documentation. session_lifetime_minutes does not seem to be helpful in my case.